# Stop "overlapping" of box-shadow when having text with a br

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use `box-shadow`s to wrap some text, in this case an anchor tag that is on two lines due to a `br`.

Unfortunately, when I do that the box shadows "overlap" each other.

I've tried a number of ways to adjust/prevent: `flex`, `position`, `grid`, etc., but have not been successful. Also, I dont have much wiggle room with the structure of the code I am working with, but can make use of CSS to address.

Any help/suggestions would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**
Please note that I am not able to re-position / move the text. What I am trying to do is make a "wrapper" around the text that doesnt affect the layout... essentially, I want to highlight where an anchor tag exists.

Here is a simple version of the code I am working with:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      a {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h2 style="font-size: 40px; letter-spacing: 0px; line-height: 44px; font-weight: 600; color: #1d1d1f;">
            <a href="http://www.cnn.com" style="">First Line of Text <br>Another Line</a>
          </h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: try with a `style="line-height:50px"` on the `<a>` tag

Comment: add your a tag in a div give it a class and then add shadow to that class and see

Comment: @RoyBogado Unfortunately, cannot change the `line-height` since that would affect the layout (going to update the question... what sucks is that I dont have too much room to maneuver with the existing code!)

Comment: Do you need the wrapping to happen on each line, or do you want the text as a whole wrapped? Can you put the box-shadow on the h2 instead?

Comment: @nisha Def a good suggestion, alas in that case the div would be the entire container, extending beyond the actual clickable area. Sorry, edited my original question to mention that I am looking to highlight only the clickable area!

Comment: @MikeTheReader What would be awesome would be a way to wrap a box on the outer edge of the text so that it represents only the clickable area. To note: Outline closely achieves this, but it also extends at some weird points...

Comment: Can you put `display: inline-block` on the `a`?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this modifies the structure of the HTML, which might be a no-go, but what about wrapping the H2 tag (which is a block element by default) with the Anchor tag (swapping them). This results in the whole block being a clickable element, and then the outline or shadow will denote that correctly.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      h2 {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="https://www.cnn.com/" style="">
            <h2 style="font-size: 40px; letter-spacing: 0px; line-height: 44px; font-weight: 600; color: #1d1d1f;">
            First Line of Text <br>Another Line
            </h2>
          </a>   
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wish I could go about it this way... another other issue is that this extends the clickable area beyond the text itself to the whole container.

Comment: you can use diplay: inline or inline block so it will not extend

Comment: @Nisha That would def fix the overlapping of the `box-shadow`, unfortunately, that would also extend the clickable area to the entire box, rather than just the text itself. Thanks for the suggestion tho!